# What is the best way to programmatically (c#) detect that a queue can no longer receive a message?

Tags: c#, error-handling, queue, msmq

We need a deterministic/consistent way of knowing if a particular queue (local/remote) is backed up (i.e. can no longer receive a message) or not before sending another message to it. The best solution I've seen so far is to get a message count (in an efficient way) on the given queue & then make a determination to send the message or not.

What is the best practice here outside of catching exception X or Y & re-trying? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If a queue has reached it's quota size then new messages will be rejected. You would need to monitor the total message size for the queue, not the total message number. The number of messages is not used by MSMQ to determine whether quota is reached or not.

Alternatively, if you are using the Dead Letter Queue, you would be able to see a rejected message with a status that indicated the destination queue had reached quota. I would regard that method as more efficient than remotely checking queue stats.